# How do I add an icon to this token code?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I’ve taken an interest in Ethereum and it’s smart contracts and in my free time I’ve been experimenting around a bit, however I’m very new to it so keep that in mind as you answer this question.

So I found a code for a token creation on the internet and I’ve been picking around at it. I was able to create customized token on the testnet, but I haven't figured out how to give it an icon like a lot of other real tokens have. I have a link to the code below, what steps would I need to take to give it an icon?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VZH9dFTxR1igbouyPcUSZWH8QETp8eZozbNmm74mBLY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can set your Token's symbol like this for an icon:

```
 string public constant symbol = "";
```

Comment: Okay, so I can see the icon in the transaction (although it's not a smile) but cannot see the icon in metamask (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xb8f692f4d76dcc70373ecdd4792d930df9402a72). Also how does one have an icon that's not a character (or is that impossible)? Last, I've updated the google doc to include the new code I used.

Answer (score 1):

I've reply to this very same question here -> [How to verify token after etherscan, and submit icon](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31902/how-to-verify-token-after-etherscan-and-submit-icon/31908#31908)

To do this you’ll need to go to the [Etherscan Contact Us Page](https://etherscan.io/contactus) and send them an e-mail with the following information:

```
Firstly, check that your token contract source code has been verified.

1. Contract Address: 

2. Official Site URL:

3. Link to download a 28x28png icon logo:

4. Official Contact Email Address:
```

They have a full explanating of what information you have to send, just select "Update Token Information in the Contact Form:

[image]