# How to verify token after etherscan, and submit icon

Tags: etherscan

Sorry, my English is not good, I verified my token on etherscan, but I do not know how to change the token's icon.
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know if the process to verify has changed, but you need to send your ICON image by e-mail.

To do this you’ll need to go to the [Etherscan Contact Us Page](https://etherscan.io/contactus) and send them an e-mail with the following information:

```
Firstly, check that your token contract source code has been verified.

1. Contract Address: 

2. Official Site URL:

3. Link to download a 28x28png icon logo:

4. Official Contact Email Address:
```

They have a full explanating of what information you have to send, just select "Update Token Information in the Contact Form:

[image]

Comment: This is no longer correct, you need to https://etherscan.io/tokenupdate/ (which might require first verifying the contract source and ownership) as noted in Alexey Barsuk's answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/85403/2256

Answer (score 3):

Now the process has changed. You should go to https://etherscan.io/tokenupdate/0xCONTTRACT_ADDRESS. Also you can find this link if you go to [https://etherscan.io/token/0xCONTTRACT_ADDRESS->Info->Update](https://etherscan.io/token/0xCONTTRACT_ADDRESS-%3EInfo-%3EUpdate). Yo'll be asked to sign some data with private key to ensure that you are contarct creator. And thean you'll be able to add information using special form.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the bottom of the etherscan page, and there should be a "Contact Us".

Just follow the instruction from there and someone from the etherscan team will email you about whether the changes were made or if they need something else.