# Token contract source code not verified

Tags: solidity, etherscan, contract-verification

Hi i have create my token with your code i have use
https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/eip20/EIP20.sol
end
https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/eip20/EIP20Interface.sol
i have create my token ETQ in https://remix.ethereum.org (Real not test )

Now i have to add link of my website and logo to do that i need to verify my source code

How i can do that ?

Where i can see my Constructor Arguments ABI-encoded ?

Please help me

My code in https://remix.ethereum.org 
i have two file

EIP20Interface.sol

```
    // Abstract contract for the full ERC 20 Token standard
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;


contract EIP20Interface {
    /* This is a slight change to the ERC20 base standard.
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply);
    is replaced with:
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    This automatically creates a getter function for the totalSupply.
    This is moved to the base contract since public getter functions are not
    currently recognised as an implementation of the matching abstract
    function by the compiler.
    */
    /// total amount of tokens
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
    /// @return The balance
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance);

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    /// @param _from The address of the sender
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

    /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_spender` to spend `_value` tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @param _value The amount of tokens to be approved for transfer
    /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

    /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining);

    // solhint-disable-next-line no-simple-event-func-name  
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value); 
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}
```

End in Taouaf.sol i have this

```
/*
Implements EIP20 token standard: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
.*/


pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./EIP20Interface.sol";


contract Taouaf is EIP20Interface {

    uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;
    /*
    NOTE:
    The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
    They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
    Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
    */
    string public name;                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
    uint8 public decimals;                //How many decimals to show.
    string public symbol;                 //An identifier: eg SBX

    function Taouaf(
        uint256 _initialAmount,
        string _tokenName,
        uint8 _decimalUnits,
        string _tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;               // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = _initialAmount;                        // Update total supply
        name = _tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        decimals = _decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        symbol = _tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        }
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }   
}
```

My ABI 
is

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000033b2e3c9fd0803ce80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e4574686572205175616c6966656400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000034554510000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

How i can put this code here https://etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x38f10839dcbf15936f79bee139ceaf484edaca46

to validate my TOKEN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify token after etherscan, and submit icon](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31902/how-to-verify-token-after-etherscan-and-submit-icon)

Comment: to do this i have to verified my TOKEN

Comment: Ah, apologies, misread your question. Have a look at this first: https://etherscan.io/verifyContract Or have you seen this already, and you're specifically asking only about the ABI encoding part?

Comment: (I've removed my suggested duplicate.)

Comment: Thankyou  can you see my post i have updated with my source code please

Comment: Even if that is not the solution: your ABI is not an ABI but most likely bytecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How i can do that ?

1. Generate flat sol file from your two source files, for example, with [solidity-flattener](https://github.com/poanetwork/solidity-flattener). Insert content of this flat file to "Enter the Solidity Contract Code below" field
2. Choose the version of compiler you used in Remix
3. Choose optimized flag true/false depending on what was this flag switched or not in Remix
4. Copy contract name from the source and paste it to "Contract name" field

> Where i can see my Constructor Arguments ABI-encoded ?

5. Etherscan automatically inserted Constructor Arguments ABI-encoded. You shouldn't take care of them.
6. Click "Verify and Publish" button

I verified your contract with these steps: https://etherscan.io/address/0x38f10839dcbf15936f79bee139ceaf484edaca46#code